# Setting Up Multi-Host GPU Training Environment for SFTTrainer

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, multi-gpu, large-language-model

I have a multi-host environment with the following GPU configuration:

- Host1: GPU1
- Host2: GPU2
- Host3: GPU3, GPU4
- Host4: GPU5, GPU6

To make sure that all available GPUs are used for training I'm using following `toy-code` on Host1 in a Jupyter Notebook:

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
from trl import SFTTrainer

# Load the dataset
dataset = load_dataset("imdb", split="train")

# Initialize the SFTTrainer with multi-GPU support
trainer = SFTTrainer(
    "NousResearch/Llama-2-70b-hf",
    train_dataset=dataset,
    dataset_text_field="text",
    max_seq_length=512,
)

# Start training
trainer.train()
```

I would like to know how to configure this setup to enable the code to run on multiple GPUs across multiple hosts using the `SFTTrainer` for training. Any assistance in achieving this would be highly appreciated.